# What Is The Recommended Way To Backup OS X Open Directory?

Tags: backup, mac-osx, mac-osx-server, opendirectory

We have recently bought a Mac Mini preloaded with Mountain Lion Server to use as an Open Directory master, and I'm not clear on how the data for Open Directory is supposed to be backed up.

We are currently using Time Machine to backup the system, and Apple documentation just briefly says that the ServerBackup facility will backup the services.

I know that the opendirectorybackup script exists and runs slapconfig, but the target file is not being updated. If I run slapconfig -backupdb manually it works. I have experimented briefly running ServerBackup manually from the command-line, but the opendirectory/ folder that it creates in /.ServerBackups/ is empty.

How is this supposed to work? I'm a Linux guy and new to Mac system administration, so all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can backup the OD Master through bash or another method is to use OD Replicas, there is a nice explanation of it on [Jon Brown's blog](http://www.jonsblog.org/2010/12/20/backing-up-the-od-master/).